# How to reset margins in react-native?

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

Still getting used to react-native styling. I noticed that resetting margins works slightly different from normal web. For the context I'm using react-native for web.

If you do the following

```
<View style=[{ verticalMargin: 10 }, { margin: 0 }] />
```

My expectation would be the View getting all margins reset to 0, but in fact vertical margin isn't reset, the top and bottom margins keep 10 as their values. That doesn't make sense to me, according to [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style)

> the last style in the array has precedence

Is it because `verticalMargin` is more specific than `margin`?

Comment: I don't think your code: `<View style=[{ verticalMargin: 10 }, { margin: 0 }] />` can work...

Comment: @DinhNguyen what exactly do you suspect isn't going to work?

Comment: Because I just copy your code and got the error: `JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **common issue** we face in react native developments, while working with reusable styles or components.

**To fix** this margin issue, you may need to **reset margin values from each side** of the view or any other component.

ex.

```
<View style={
    [
      {
        marginVertical: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 20
      },
      {
        marginTop: 0,
        marginBottom: 0,
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginRight: 0,
      },
    ]
  }
/>
```

Comment: ok, this is different from normal web, but good to know and to be honest it's not so surprising considering how many target environments react-native has.